# Remove subscribers from Auto Suppression List

Tags: marketing-cloud

How do we delete subscribers (emails) from Auto suppression list using SSJS. Also, Auto suppression list maintain at SF end or application level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Delete All Records

The following script uses WSProxy to delete all records from an auto-suppression list.

Replace `AutoSuppressionExternalKey` with the external key of your Auto Suppression List.

```js
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
 
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var res;
var autoSupListDE = 'AutoSuppressionExternalKey'
 
function clearAutoSuppressionList(){
    var action = 'ClearData';
    var options = {};
    var props = {
        CustomerKey:autoSupListDE
    };
    var res = prox.performItem("DataExtension",props,action,options);
}
 
function main(){
  clearAutoSuppressionList();
}
 
main();
</script>
```

### Delete Single Record

Piyush asked how to delete a specific record from an auto suppression list. As auto-suppression lists are effectively Data Extensions, the following SSJS platform function will remove an individual record (based on their email address) from an auto-suppression list:

```js
<script runat="server">
   var deleteRow = Platform.Function.DeleteData('AutoSuppressionListName',['Email Address'],['sam@sample.com']);
</script>
```

### Delete Multiple Records

Piyush also ask how to iterate through a Data Extension containing email addresses for deletion, then remove them from the auto suppression list.

The following script will achieve this, where `toDelete` is the External Key of the DE containing Email Addresses to delete (which includes a field named 'Email' with the email addresses for deletion), and `AutoSuppressionExternalKey` is the external key of the auto suppression list.

```js
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

     var deleteEmails = DataExtension.Init("toDelete");
     var data = deleteEmails.Rows.Retrieve();

     for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

       var email = data[i].Email;

       var deleteRow = Platform.Function.DeleteData('AutoSuppressionExternalKey',['Email Address'],[email]);

    };

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Eliot. Also, what if I want to delete specific one from list ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide this option too.

Comment: Thanks Eliot for your kind response. One last ask. What if we want the script to loop through the DE and remove every email address in the DE from the identified list. Means remove from Auto Suppression DE by comparing any list or DE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi  @EliotHarper, I have a doubt when I create auto suppression list will it be only used with trigger send emails or it will be used with all email send by sender profile/send calcification associated with the auto suppression list?

Comment: @RushikeshPandit, it's not limited to Triggered Sends. It's based on the sender profile or classification. Refer to [my video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4n7HfLbi2YA).

Comment: @EliotHarper thank you for a response, I asked because we wanted to use auto suppression list for email send through sales cloud. So I think it should work right? as we have an option of selecting the send calcification in the Email Send tab.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing this info, really useful. Also to mention that in the ***Delete*** function, *Suppression List Name* is required instead *AutoSuppressionExternalKey*.

Correct: Platform.Function.DeleteData('Suppression List Name',['Email Address'],['xxx@yahoo.com']);

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352294&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Agreed, name worked for me, external key did not.