# Trying to Remove a Subscriber from Auto Suppressed List

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I am following Eliot Harper's answer on [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236460/remove-subscribers-from-auto-suppression-list).

His code in "Delete All Records" works fine for me, but his code from "Delete Single Record" results in a 500.

I included snippets from his answer below for reference

**(500 Error) Delete Single Record**

```js
<script runat="server">
   var deleteRow = Platform.Function.DeleteData('AutoSuppressionExternalKey',['Email Address'],['sam@sample.com']);
</script>
```

**(Works Fine) Delete All Records**

```js
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var res;
var autoSupListDE = 'AutoSuppressionExternalKey'

function clearAutoSuppressionList(){
    var action = 'ClearData';
    var options = {};
    var props = {
        CustomerKey:autoSupListDE
    };
    var res = prox.performItem("DataExtension",props,action,options);
}

function main(){
  clearAutoSuppressionList();
}

main();
</script>
```

It seems to be working fine for other people, so I am not sure what is going on.

Note: I cannot comment on the original thread because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Can you share the actual piece of script you wrote with all your parameters?

Comment: That's odd. Note, auto suppression lists are effectively Data Extensions, so you can interact with them in the same way. I definitely tested this code when I answered and it follows [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionDeleteData.htm). Please can you wrap a JavaScript try/catch statement around your code and let me know what the error is?

Comment: This may be a silly guess..... but I faced something similar to this...... can you try the `NAME of the DataExtension`... instead of the EXTERNAL KEY

Comment: @EliotHarper I am using cloud pages, so I cannot Write the exception or store as AMPScript variable and output. But I did try VishalKumarCV's suggestion to use the DataExtension's name instead of External Key and it worked-go figure! Thanks for sharing. I will add an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @VishalKumarCV's suggestion and used the list Name instead of the AutoSuppressionExternalKey and it worked!