# searching contacts in Auto-Suppression Lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, sender-authentication-package

I want to know if a email adress is member of a Auto-Suppression Lists. 
(without exporting it as an csv). Is there a chance?

Comment: "List" is a misnomer when it comes to Auto-Suppression.  It's technically a Data Extension that's suppressed from the normal interface locations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query your Auto-Suppression list using SQL.

In this case, try something like this in Query Studio:

```
SELECT 
[Email Address] AS Email 
FROM [YOUR_LISTS_NAME] 
WHERE [Email Address] = 'youremail@email.com'
```

Depending on the result, you'll know if the email adress is in your list or not..

Edit:

As Adam pointed out on the comments, Auto-Suppression list is basically a Data Extension. Therefore, we can query it, treat it in SSJS as it is: a Data Extension using Data Extensions functions.. (check out [Eliot's example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236460/remove-subscribers-from-auto-suppression-list/236604#236604))